# Differences in pointer syntax

Tags: c, pointers

I've been told that it doesn't matter where you put the asterisk in a pointer.

```
int* p;
int *p;
```

are the same. But once it gets complex I get confused. For example, you can do this:

```
int (*(p));
int** (*(p));
int*** (*(p)) {};
```

Are there any difference between these declarations?

Comment: "it does not matter where you put the asterisk in a pointer" means that "it does not matter whether or not you have whitespace before, after, both, or not at all". It does not mean that you can put `*`'s everywhere randomly.

Comment: Why would you put all the `(` and `)` in code like this? Are you mixing this up with function pointers?

Comment: @4386427 of course there is no use for parentheses in the 1st and 2nd declarations in the second fragment, but it is legal to add parentheses around a type like that. 3rd is a syntax error though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I know that :-) I was just considering the reason behind this question,  i.e. will you ever meet code like that? Are there any situations where it actually makes sense to put parentheses in variable definitions?

Comment: (incorrectly said "type", you cannot parenthesize the type here) @4386427 . It could be useful for macro expansions.

Answer (score 6):

`int (*(p));` is a pointer to `int`.

`int** (*(p));` is a pointer to pointer to pointer to `int`.

`int*** (*(p)) {};` is invalid syntax in C.